# update array item in all document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have collection like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a2e645e146ca85717059965"),
"number" : [ 
    1, 
    2, 
    3, 
    4, 
    5, 
    6
]
}

 /* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a2e647f146ca85717059973"),
"number" : [ 
    5, 
    4, 
    3
]
 }

  /* 3 */
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e6491146ca85717059977"),
  "number" : [ 
    4, 
    5, 
    6, 
    7, 
    8, 
    9, 
    1, 
    1, 
    1
]
}
```

now i want to change all `1` to `a` means replacing 1 with a so i write this query :

```
db.getCollection('mtest1').update({},{"$set":{"number.$[i]":"a"}},{arrayFilters:[{i:1}]})
```

but i get this error :

```
cannot use the part (number of number.$[i]) to traverse the element ({number: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]})
```

i search on SF and find some solution but none of theme work for me

Comment: Are you on 3.6 mongo version ? arrayFilters is available from 3.6

Comment: @Veeram you right , my version is 3.4